# Planning an Azure eco-system

Tags: asp.net, azure

What is the recommended way to set up Azure for an eco-system of services and sites?

We have a set of .Net web services and and ASP.Net web sites that are working fine on our test server. The web sites uses REST calls to talk to the services, which mobile devices also access. We are now in the process of learning about Azure so that we can gain from the up-time offered.

We are wondering if we should be using multiple "Hosted Services", one for each part of the eco-system, or whether we should be looking at multiple "Deployment"s within a single "Hosted Service". It appears that multiple hosted services may cause additional costs with more compute instances needed, which would seem unnecessary for systems that talk to each other. But are there benefits to doing it that way, or no additional costs, or something we've not thought of?

We'd rather learn from the mistakes of others, so welcome recommendations on the way to set our system up on Azure.

Comment: Anyone suggest a good place to get an answer?